# What's the best way to split up a JSON formatted string from DynamoDB in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a project in AWS Lambda using JavaScript and I am receiving data from a DynamoDB table in JSON format which i am then converting to a string. I need to find the easiest way to split up this string so each column from the database has it's own value saved in it's own string variable. 
Here's an example of my code:

```
function readDynamoItem(params, callback) {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

    console.log('reading item from DynamoDB table');

    dynamodb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else{
            console.log(data); // successful response
            callback(JSON.stringify(data));
        }               
    });

}
```

The response for callback would result in:

```
{\"Items\":[{\"id\":{\"S\":\"5\"},\"message\":{\"S\":\"hello\"}}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":6}
```

So in this case i would need a string called id containing "5" and a string called message containing "hello". I have looked into using the .split() function but I'm not sure how I would just get the string without all the {\"S\":\" etc. part 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse method? You got JSON from Dynamo, not string, so you need to work with JSON, not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` varaible already holds an object. Passing that to callback w/o stringifying it is the proper way. With that callback you can easily addres the ID field like this:

```
var id = data.Items[0].id;
var message = data.Items[0].message
```

You may add some logic regarding the effectiv number of items in the array.

Comment: Perfect and then I can just do JSON.stringify(message) whenever i want to print it as a string right??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the data as JSON not string, and then:

```
var myObj;
var items = data.Items;
for(var key in items) {
    myObj[key] = items[key];
}
```